# Loop doesn't break. C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char puzzle[100];
        int i;
        int k=0; 


        for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
                if(k==1)
                {
                        if(getchar()=='\n')
                                break;
                        else
                                k=0;
                }
                scanf(" %c",&puzzle[i]);

                if(getchar()=='\n')
                        k=1;
          }
}
```

This code is supposed to break the loop when 2 newline characters are entered  But it doesn't break the loop always.

Comment: The `scanf(" %c", &puzzle[i])` call skips white space, including newlines.

Comment: It should break the loop if a single letter is entered followed by 2 newlines. It won't break the loop if no letters are entered, or more than one letter.  Also if the input is `a\nb\n` then the `b` will be discarded so you need to rethink your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the break statement does not break out the if clause, It breaks out the nearest loop(for,while) or switch clause. I guess you are expecting it to break out the if condition.

So in your code when you enter two '\n' it will come out of the for loop and continue execution and exists from the program.